# How to set default volume for microphone in startup in Win10

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone

Every time I restart or shut down and then turn on my PC the volume of the microphone (in volume mixer) is set to high.

Then I hear a bad noise (I think you call it coupled speakers, I'm apologize I'm not native English speaker).

I set the volume to OFF then restart and the volume returns to ON.

How I set OFF forever?

I have this problem also in Win7 (previos update to Windows 10) and now. I'm using a Sony Vaio i5

Comment: Are you using Windows Sounds control panel or specific software?

Comment: I'm using the default volume mixer

Comment: What happens if you do this? Open Recording Devices > Open up properties of the mic > Click Advanced > Disable the exclusive mode. Please provide your feedback once you do. From here you could also adjust microphone levels and enhancements.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do the following.

To get started, first right-click on the “speaker” icon in the task-bar next to the clock

In the pop up dialogue box, click “Recording Devices”

Click on the recording tab.

Click on the microphone that has the green check box by it.

Click properties in the lower right.

Click on levels.

Adjust your Microphone to 0 on the slider and click OK.

That should do it.

Comment: I try that before write my question here. **It does not works**. It work until I turn off the computer. When I turn it on the volume is on and high.